# Как восстановить git репозиторий, если я знаю логин, пароль

Tags: github

я знаю логин, пароль и ссылка на реп есть, но при входе он требует подтверждения с почти, типа мы прислали вам письмо на почту A......@yandex.ru а я понятия не имею что это за почта и где она и как к ней добраться, я конечно могу скопировать весь код, но мне хочется восстановить именно реп, чтобы там даты сохранялись, когда я пушил, может кто знает кому писать за восстановлением, ещё раз повторяю, у меня точно правильный логин и пароль есть, абсурднее некуда блин.

Comment: Поменял метку на github, т.к. вопрос не про git. Если это не гитхаб, то исправьте сами

Comment: в случае гитхаба, я бы начал с страницы https://support.github.com/ и вперед

Comment: Если репозиторий открытый (по тексту вопроса создается такое впечатление), то просто склонируйте его, коммиты ("даты сохранялись, когда я пушил") будут на месте

Comment: @insolor реп открытый всё так, а можешь накидать тезисно что и как делать, а то я что-то даже найти не могу в инете как пошагово сделать это, типа создам я др аккаунт, как мне все репозитории скопировать сразу, у меня их штук 20, ну всм если я не ошибаюсь, я за реп принимаю отдельный проект, то есть у меня есть аккаунт и там около 20-и проектов, я бы хотел всё это сохранить в другой аккаунт

Comment: Вообще, проще всего через импорт. На старом репозитории нажать зеленую кнопку "Code" - ssh, скопировать ссылку. Потом нажать на кнопку "+" справа сверху на github, "Import repository", вставить ссылку, нажать "Begin import", дождаться окончания импорта. И так с каждым репозиторием.

Comment: спасибо.........